# Why is using infinity (oo) in sympy faster than providing an integer upper bound?

Tags: python, performance, sympy

Consider the following sample code ([Repl.it](https://repl.it/IgAK/0)):

```
from sympy import *;
import time;

k = symbols('k', integer = True);

start = time.time();
s_a = float(summation((pow(-1,(k+1))/k) * (pow((4.0/5.0),(k+1))), (k,1,oo)));
print("Result: " + str(s_a) + ".  Time to compute - " + str(time.time() - start)  + " seconds")

N = 1000;
start = time.time();
s_b = float(summation((pow(-1,(k+1))/k) * (pow((4.0/5.0),(k+1))), (k,1,N)));
print("Result: " + str(s_b) + ".  Time to compute: " + str(time.time() - start)  + " seconds")
```

The output is:

```
Result: 0.470229331921695.  Time to compute: 0.371837854385376 seconds
Result: 0.470229331921696.  Time to compute: 1.1281118392944336 seconds
```

Why is the execution time significantly faster when using the range 1 to ∞ than when using a range from 1 to 1000 in the above example?

Comment: Can you edit to add the series you're actually computing?

Comment: Note that you can replace `pow` by the `**` operator in Python and you are using far too many brackets. Your summand can be shortened to `(-1)**(k+1)/k * (4/5.)**(k+1)`. If you employ simple arithmetics, it can be even further simplified to `(-4/5.)**(k+1)/k`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite series you want to compute is essentially the [mercator series](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) or first [polylogarithm](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).
There is an analytical result for this, which SymPy knows and uses.
You can also see this if you replace `4.0/5.0` by `Rational(4,5)` and remove the `float` conversion, in which case you will obtain `-4*log(5)/5 + 4*log(9)/5` for the infinite sum (which can be simplified to `4/5*log(9/5)`).

By contrast, there is no analytical result for the truncated series (summing to `N`), which is why SymPy has to actually numerically add all the summands, which takes much longer.

For completeness’ sake, it should be noted that when you convert to `float`, the logarithm needs to be evaluated numerically, which again [happens through some truncated power series or similar](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Calculation), but in this case, the summation happens in highly optimised compiled code instead of Python.